# rsyslog.conf config check issues

Tags: config, rsyslog

Running rsyslogd -N 1, I receive two complains :

> rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 27: parameter **'RebindInterval' not known** -- typo in config file? [v8.27.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]

and a complain about last line :

> rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 43: warnings occured in file '/etc/rsyslog.conf' around line 43 [v8.27.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]

> rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 43: invalid character '(' - is there an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [v8.27.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]

> rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 43: warnings occured in file '/etc/rsyslog.conf' around line 43 [v8.27.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]

> rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 43: invalid character '=' - is there an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [v8.27.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]

> rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 43: invalid character '"' - is there an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [v8.27.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]

- It' s strange because rebindInterval should be known : https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omfwd.html#rebindinterval
- Also last line is straight as in the doc : https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/include.html#include-multiple-files

The config is as follows rsyslog 8.28 on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
# /etc/rsyslog.conf Configuration file for rsyslog

module(load="imuxsock")

module(
    load="imklog"
    LogPath="/proc/kmsg"
    )

module(load="imudp")
input(
    type="imudp"
    port="514"
)

module(load="imtcp")
input(
    type="imtcp"
    port="514"
)

module(
    load="builtin:omfwd"
    # RebindInterval="5000" # ERROR shown by rsyslogd -N 1 : parameter 'RebindInterval' not known.
)

module(
    load="builtin:omfile"
    template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat"
    fileOwner="syslog"
    fileGroup="syslog"
    fileCreateMode="0640"
    dirCreateMode="0755"
)

global(
    preserveFQDN="on"
    umask="0022"
)

include(file="/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf")
```